# How to scrape data from Wikipedia using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, wikipedia

I need to create a table in R for list of clothing retailers by country using the webpage https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Clothing_brands_by_country.

I tried looking at various links but could not find anything that worked. 
Basic need right now is to be able to extract links from a page and then coerce it to open and scrape data from it.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))


path<-"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Clothing_brands_by_country"
webpage <- getURL(path)
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)
pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE, encoding=FALSE)
```

Comment: do not have an option...I know R for standard analysis, not for scraping. Can do this with Python but not an option unfortunately

Comment: Check the rvest package and the demo's. That might help you further. Or just copy and paste the information.

Comment: What does your code do at present?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WikipediaR/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, not knowing HTML was the main problem. :

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem",     package = "RCurl")))
path<-"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Clothing_brands_by_country"
webpage <- getURL(path)
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)
pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE, encoding=FALSE) 
q='//a[@class="CategoryTreeLabel  CategoryTreeLabelNs14 CategoryTreeLabelCategory"]'

a<-xpathSApply(pagetree, q, xmlGetAttr,'href')
t <- gsub('\\s', '', a,)
x<-data.frame(t)
x$pos<-gregexpr(pattern ='of_',x$t)
x$country<-substr(substr(x$t,x$pos,10000),4,10000)
x$url<-paste("https://en.wikipedia.org",x$t,sep="")

chk<-x[1,]
chk2<-chk$url
country<-chk$country
webpage <- getURL(chk2)
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)
pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE, encoding=FALSE)
q<-'//div[@class="mw-content-ltr"]//ul/li/a'
a<-xpathSApply(pagetree, q, xmlGetAttr,'title')
n<-data.frame(a)
n$country<-country
fin<-n

for (i in 2:25)
{
  chk<-x[i,]
  chk2<-chk$url
  country<-chk$country
  webpage <- getURL(chk2)
  webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)
  pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE, encoding=FALSE)
  q<-'//div[@class="mw-content-ltr"]//ul/li/a'
  a<-xpathSApply(pagetree, q, xmlGetAttr,'title')
  n<-data.frame(a)
  n$country<-country
  fin<-rbind(fin,n)
}
```